# How to solve React ENOENT error. when i start npm it show this error 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\react app\\new-react-app\\.next\\BUILD_ID'

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, enoent

▲ Next.js 14.0.1

- Local:        http://localhost:3000

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\react app\new-react-app.next\BUILD_ID'] {
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'open',
path: 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\react app\new-react-app\.next\BUILD_ID'
}

please solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Either start the app with:

```
npm run dev
```

Or try to first build your site like this:

```
npm run build
```

Followed by:

```
npm start
```